# Binding sprite movement to the camera or scene (AndEngine)

Tags: java, android, andengine, collision

I am using DigitalOnScreenControl to Move Player Sprite.But the Problem is that My Player Sprite goes out of Emulator Screen.I want player sprite be restricted to move in particular bounds and also camera to focus on player sprite as and when my sprite moves on.

i am trying this code:

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {

    // Auto-generated method stub
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene mScene=new Scene();
    mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));



     final int centerX=(CAMERA_WIDTH-this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getWidth())/2;
     final int centerY=(CAMERA_HEIGHT-this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight())/2;

     final Sprite player=new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);

    this.mCamera.setChaseEntity(player);
     final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler=new PhysicsHandler(player);
     player.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

     mScene.attachChild(player);

     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl=new DigitalOnScreenControl(0,CAMERA_HEIGHT-mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight(),this.mCamera,this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion,this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion,0.1f,new IOnScreenControlListener() {

        @Override
        public void onControlChange(BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,
                float pValueX, float pValueY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX*100, pValueY*100);

        }
    });


     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
     this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

     mScene.setChildScene(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);


    return mScene;
  }
```

Honestly I am Very new in `andEngine` Development 
please Help me With Heart
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Binding the Player to the Camera

What you're asking for is a form of collision handling.  Essentially, when you've moved the player outside of the scene, you want to move the player back into the scene, and you want to do that in the same update as you've moved the player, immediately after moving the player, so the out-of-scene location never gets rendered.

Lets take apart what I just said.  You move the player here:

```
physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX*100, pValueY*100);
```

Moving the player with a physicsHandler is perfectly reasonable and takes into account variable frame-rate so, so far, good job.  Now you want to move them back into the scene if they're outside it.  So we're going to need a new method.  Lets throw in a method call right after moving the player (we'll call it "adjustToSceneBinding()" so you have this:

```
physicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX*100, pValueY*100);
adjustToSceneBinding(player);
```

Sidenote, I'd rather have this method be on the player (i.e., player.adjustToSceneBinding()), but your player object is just a sprite.  I'd suggest you change that to a custom object that extends sprite so you can throw in your own code there.  In any event, lets make the adjustToSceneBinding() method.

```
public boolean adjustToSceneBinding(Sprite player) {

    // Correct the X Boundaries.
    if (player.getX() < 0) {
        player.setX(0);
    } else if (player.getX() + player.getWidth() > CAMERA_WIDTH) {
        player.setX(CAMERA_WIDTH - player.getWidth());
    }
}
```

See what I did?  If the player's X coordinate is less than zero, move them back to zero.  If the player's X PLUS the player's width is more than the camera width, move them back to the camera width minus the player width.  Don't forget the player X coordinate represents the left side of the sprite. That's why I'm taking into account the width in addition to the position for calculating the right side.

The above code only addresses left/right movement, but I'm going to let you extrapolate how to do the same for up down.

### Binding the Player to the Map Size Instead

Now, what we did so far was really intended for the situation where the map "size" is no larger than the screen.  But often what you'll want is a larger map than the screen size and a camera that chases the player around.  To do that, just replace the code above, where I referred to the CAMERA_WIDTH with a number that represents the width of your "map".  In other words, the map can be much larger than the camera.  If you use larger numbers there (than, say, the width of the camera), and you set the camera to chase the player entity (as you have), then you'll have a map where the player can move around until they hit the bounds of the map.

Hope this helps! :)